# Parce complicated JSON object

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I`ve got complicated JSON object as response. I mean what it contains subclasses. So I thinking how parse it. I created data class:

```
 @Parcelize

 data class Attachments(
  val photo:String,
  val video:String,
  val audio: audio,
  val doc: doc,
val grafity: String,
val link: String,
val note: note,
val poll: poll,
val page: String 
):Parcelable{
    companion object :Parceler <Attachments>{
    override fun create(parcel: Parcel): Attachments {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun Attachments.write(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
      }

   }

}
```

subclasses are also  described similarly

So, how to parcel it correct. I know, that I can parse all it by manual, but I searching for more elegant way for this. I want to avoid that I get confused in the code.

```
 val response = r.getString("response") as String
            val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()

            val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<WallJSON> =moshi.adapter(WallJSON::class.java)
            val wallItem = jsonAdapter.fromJson(response)
```

Adapter

```
class WallJSON() {

    @FromJson fun WallFromJson(item: Wall) {

    }
}
```

Data Class

```
   @Parcelize
   @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
   data class Wall (
   val Text:String="",
   val attachments: Attachments?,

       ):Parcelable
```

JSON

```
"response": {
"count": 8,
"items": [{
"id": 0,
"text": "",
    "attachments": [{
    "type": "photo",
    "photo": {
    "id": 00,
    "post_id": 10064,
    "height": 130,
    "url": "https://",
    "type": "m",
    "width": 87
    }, ],
    "text": ""}}]    

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use some of JSON parsing libraries ([moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi), gson etc).
And change your classes like these (example for moshi codegen):

```
@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Attachments(
    val photo: String,
    val video: String,
    val audio: Audio,
    val doc: Doc,
    val grafity: String,
    val link: String,
    val note: Note,
    val poll: Poll,
    val page: String
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Audio(
    ...
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Doc(
    ...
) : Parcelable
```

etc.

After that create an adapter and parse your json:

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
val adapter = moshi.adapter(Attachments::class.java)
val attachments = adapter.fromJson(yourJson)
```

If your json is list, try this adapter:

```
val listType: Type = Types.newParameterizedType(
    List::class.java,
    Attachments::class.java
)
val listAdapter = moshi.adapter(listType)
val attachmentsList = listAdapter.fromJson(yourJson)
```

Comment: Is it parse automaticly? I mean every value from JSON gets into appropriate dataclass value? The are many data, what I wish to skip.

Comment: You can remove some fields from your data class which you don't need to parse. `attachments` variable is parsed `Attachments` object @killbit

Comment: Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: I've added adapter for list, check it please @killbit

Comment: Strange, it eats like jsonobject

Comment: Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ –

Comment: I changed gradle version to 4.0.0. It compiles. But I need to understand how work with moshi in my case

Comment: I am getting response from request as jsonObject. It find moshi on GitHub. I understand, what I need create adapter class, write logic in there for parsing

Comment: I cant understand this string ['code'] val attachmentsList = listAdapter.fromJson(yourJson) ['code'] how place there JSONObject?

Comment: Show your code and json which you want to parse @killbit

Comment: I have added code. I tryed to minimalize it for comfort. I need just understand how work with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215660/discussion-between-killbit-and-shmakova).